# Efficiently find last date in a table - Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

Say I have a rather large table in a Teradata database, "Sales" that has a daily record for every sale and I want to write a SQL statement that limits this to the latest date only. This will not always be the previous day, for example, if it was a Monday the latest date would be the previous Friday.

I know I can get the results by the following:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Sales s
JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(SalesDate) as SalesDate 
      FROM Sales
) sd 
ON s.SalesDate=sd.SalesDt
```

I am not knowledgable on how it would process the subquery and since Sales is a large table would there be a more efficient way to do this given there is not another table I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably fine, if you have an index on `salesdate`.

If there is only one row, then I would recommend:

```
select top 1 s.*
from sales s
order by salesdate desc;
```

In particular, this should make use of an index on `salesdate`.

If there is more than one row, use `top 1 with ties`.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked and there is an index on that column so I will use that.

Answer (score 2):

Another (more flexible) way to get the *top n* utilizes OLAP-functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales s
QUALIFY
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SalesDate DESC) = 1
```

This will return *all* rows with the max date. If you want only one of them switch to ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Is there any efficiency gain/loss doing it this way versus the way in my OP?

Comment: The only way to tell is to compare the actual resource usage based on DBQL. OLAP functions tend to be better even for such simple tasks...